# The "vmStatsProvider" is successfully initialized for this virtual machine

Tags: vmware

I'm running my application on a virtual machine. Every time an exception is being thrown, I get this message in event log.

The "vmStatsProvider" is successfully initialized for this virtual machine.

This application that I'm writing connect to another server to get notification in a form of string.

I want to find out, what does this means.

Appreciate any help on this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c04179838

> ### Cause
>
> If user installs the VMware tools with all components, some Windows
> Performance Monitor counters will be added to the VM. When this
> counters are available, the Events are often caused by a Third Party
> Monitoring Tool.
>
> ### Answer/Solution
>
> Install the VMware Tools without the Perfmon Component :
>
> `setup.exe ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=PerfMon`
>
> This prevent the installation of the additional Windows performance
> counters in the VM and the Events are gone.